# Как сосредоточится на разработке алгоритма?

Tags: алгоритм

В голове крутятся идеи что и как написать , но нет понимания как это объединить и сгруппировать. И так стало интересно, кто и как концентрируется при разработке +- сложных алгоритмов? Как разделяете на последовательность действий? Как группируете?

P.S. Новичок, пишу для себя, написал прототип+- рабочий и хочу улучшить.

Comment: Все свои мысли сразу стараетесь закодить, для получения желаемого результата. Естественно, это должен быть максимально читаемый код, для последующего рефакторинга. Когда ваш алгоритм работает, начинаете оптимизировать и рефачить ваш код. Желательна также разработка через тдд ( через написание тестов) это позволит сразу найти проблемы при рефакторинге

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Вряд ли на него можно ответить что-то не в духе КО (типа, `абстрагируй задачу, разделяй ее на части и повторяй, пока каждое действие не станет очевидно` (еще такой подход называют программированием сверху вниз или иерархической декомпозицией) или `возьми входные данные, представь, во что они должны превратиться и придумай последовательность элементарных шагов, которые сделают такое преобразование`).

Comment: Посмотрите такую книжку - Левитин, Алгоритмы: введение в разработку и анализ. Там все как раз крутится вокруг того, как разрабатывать алгоритмы, а не вокруг готовых решений.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для разработки алгоритма не привязываюсь ни к какому языку. Сперва просто расписываю по шагам на бумаге что и как должно происходить.

Подход "сверху-вниз". То есть сперва крупными блоками, затем каждый из этих крупных блоков разбиваю на более мелкие и так до тех пор, пока дальше бить не будет никакого смысла.

Затем пишу прототип решения и тесты к нему уже на компе. И уже этот прототип довожу до ума, рефакторя, профилируя и оптимизируя те или иные участки кода.

Очень полезно написать тесты, так как они помогают контролировать, остался-ли код работоспособным после того или иного изменения.

Кроме того использую статические анализаторы кода. Им не стоит доверять на все сто, но они часто дают полезную информацию о том, где может быть потенциально опасный с точки зрения возникновения багов код.

Answer (score 2):

Для составления того или иного алгоритма необходимы не плохие знания языка на котором пишешь, так как в зависимости от использования тех или иных инструментов этого языка ты можешь написать алгоритм. А хороший или плохой он будет - зависит как раз от этих знаний. Например, в ООП есть паттерны - шаблоны реализации под те или иные задачи, благодаря которым их реализация и дальнейшая поддержка будет проходить с минимальными проблемами. Код, (желательно, практически обязательно) должен придерживаться определенным правилам проектирования: например, таким как KISS, SOLID, DRY и т.д..

Я обычно для начала, реализую какую либо заготовку кода, не отшлифованную, так сказать, смотря на определенные условия, которые должны выполняться в коде. Пытаясь, соответствовать им, параллельно думаю как код можно улучшать, какими способами сделать так, что бы он был максимально производителен и оптимизирован.(Тут нам и понадобятся  различные знания)

Различные знания помогают за счет своего разнообразия выбрать наилучший вариант из возможных.

Пример:

Разные способы реализации в алгоритмах - https://tproger.ru/articles/computational-complexity-explained/

Множество различных вариантов сортировки - https://habr.com/ru/post/335920/

Дополню, если мысли придут